# Precautions to take before replacing Hard drive in desktop

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, disk, data-recovery, disk-management

i am using Ubuntu .my hard disk is aged so i have to change it.i want to keep my data as it is and if possible.can any one please guideline some points .steps to take for successful hard disk replacement in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 4):

I would do this like this:

- Add the 2nd hard disc to your system.
- Install Ubuntu on that hard disc.
- Boot into it.
- Copy all files you need from the 1st hard disc over to the 2nd one.
- Format the 1st one and add it as a spare partition.

Just remember to make regular backups for files on that old hard disc. If you are lucky it will last another few years.

Alternative:

- Make a live DVD if you do not have one yet.
- Put all files you need to save to a DVD.
- Remove old disc; put in new disc.
- Install from live DVD
- Restore the files you saved.

---

Just to be hmmm annoying: I expect anyone always to make backups. Even when NOT messing with your system.

Comment: I would add "make a backup" as a first step BEFORE opening the machine and connecting the new disk. You never know.

Comment: I assume a backup is a given >:-D @Rmano

Comment: If you can install them both, you might look into using dd to clone the existing disk onto the new disk, then swap the new for the old. If it doesn't work, you can always follow Rinzwind's excellent plan. Just make sure when you use `dd` that you don't confuse the source for the target. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Answer (score 0):

A small observation on Hard disks. They some times go for decades the problem is if surface errors turn up then clear then something is wrong and you need to get that component out of the system (it could be the cable) but of cause hard disks do fail have you had a warning when the computer starts up?

Avoid deleting and then adding partitions to a hard disk because the surface errors found and marked previously will have to be found again slowing access time down.